# Rails: display an error to users that is produced in an after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I go about rescuing an error that was generated in an after_save callback, and then ultimately display it to the user? The code in my model looks something like this:

```
Class MyModel
  after_save :call_other_class_responsible_for_parsing

  def call_other_class_responsible_for_parsing
    # this method is used by multiple models
    ModelTwo.parse_css
  end
end
```

In my controller, I currently redirect the user elsewhere if the update was successful, however, I consider the update to be successful if it passed all of the existing validations **and** there were no errors in the callback (from the Less::Parser).

EDIT:

I mixed up my thoughts in my original question. MyModel gets saved from it's corresponding controller, which then runs the after_save callback from the model. Inside call_other_class_responsible_for_parsing, there is a call to another model, let's say ModelTwo, which does the Less parsing. I've tried using code like this:

```
  def self.parse_css
    @my_model = MyModel.find(1)
    css_to_compile = Less::Parser.new.parse(css).to_css
    rescue Less::Error => error
      @my_model.errors[:base] << "Error message"    
      false
    end
  end
```

But the `false` does not prevent the transaction from succeeding, therefore a redirect happens.

Comment: Do you save your `MyModel` object in several places? If not, you could just call `my_method` after a successful `my_model.save` instead of using a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use transaction :

```
def create
  MyModel.transaction do
    @my_model.save
    @my_model.my_method
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
    # rescue active record exception here
  rescue Less::Error => exception
    # rescue less error here
end
```

This remove the need for a callback.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Callback chains are implicitly wrapped in a transaction. When a callback returns `false` or raises an exception then the whole transaction is rolled back and saving fails.

In your case, you're parsing some CSS, so I'm not sure whether `after_save` is the right place for this. **I recommend you give validations a try**. Consider the following:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :valid_css

  private

  def parsed_css
    @parsed_css ||= Less::Parser.new.parse(css).to_css
  end

  def valid_css
    parsed_css
  rescue Less::Error => error
    errors.add(:css, "Cannot parse CSS: #{error}")
  end
end
```

This will parse the CSS *before* saving the object and add an error if it's invalid. Also, the result of `#to_css` will be stored so that you won't need to recompute it. **This is the approach that I'd recommend**.

If you'd like to stick with `after_save` then you should **raise an exception to abort the transaction**. In your case, it's simply about not rescuing `Less::Error`:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :compile_css

  private

  def compile_css
    css_to_compile = Less::Parser.new.parse(css).to_css
  end
end
```

If you're having trouble deciding  which approach to use then leave a question below and I'll help.

Comment: Thank you, I tried errors.add and return false with no luck. I edited the question as well.

Comment: @mycellius, you're right. I was confused. In order to abort the transaction from an after_* callback you need to raise an exception. I updated my answer to reflect this. Also, why not use `validate` for this?

Comment: I tried your method with no luck. The reason I can't use validations before saving is because the parser evaluates MyModels attributes using a binding, so it somewhat 'injects' the already saved values into a template which gets parsed by Less. Here is the tutorial I am following: [link](https://matteodepalo.github.io/blog/2013/02/01/refactor-replace-method-with-method-object/)

Comment: I didn't notice the changes in your edit. Do you have to _save_ `MyModel` before parsing? I think you should be perfectly fine if you pass the instance (saved or not) to `parse_css`. In the tutorial you're following, try changing `theme_id` to `theme` and pass the (unsaved) model.